# How is monitor acquired in case of static function?

Tags: java, static, synchronization, monitor

According to JLS [Section §8.4.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used.

In this synchronized  method move class level lock is acquired. So which Class object is exactly used for obtaining this lock. Is it  `Interface.class` or `ClassImplementingInterface.class`? If it is the later is there any scenario where we can have interface monitors? or rather does interface have a monitor?

I have read each object is associated with a monitor and in case of static locks monitor is obtained on corresponding Class object. As we can do Interface.Class which means interface has corresponding Class object can we get a lock on that monitor without explicitly saying `synchronized(Interface.class)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `interface` is a type and can therefore get its `Class<?>` object

```
public interface MyTest {}
...
Class<?> clazz = MyTest.class;
```

However, **for Java 7 and before**, your question is moot since **interfaces cannot have static methods and static methods cannot be overriden**, so it will always get the `Class` object of the class it's being called on.

```
public class StaticTest {
    public static synchronized void test() {
        // something
    }
}
```

Calling `StaticTest.test()` will synchronize on the `StaticText.class` object.

As for instance methods with a `synchronized` modifer, it would again be the calling object's monitor (lock) that you would acquire.

In Java 8, you can declare and define `static` methods in interfaces, but [they cannot be modified with the `synchronized` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4).

> ```
> InterfaceMethodModifier:
>     (one of)
>     Annotation public
>     abstract default static strictfp
> ```

It's again a non-issue.

---

To answer

> *is there any scenario where we can have interface monitors*

not with a `synchronized` modifier. But you can always use a synchronized block on an interface's `Class` object.

```
synchronized (MyTest.class) {...}
```

but really, why would you do that? I think it would be confusing for people reading your code.

Comment: Yeah kind of got confused there in static synchronization and interfaces. So basically interfaces have associated monitors and we can use it explicitly by  synchronized (Interface.class) {...}. Thanks!

Comment: @AniketThakur You are welcome. Please don't synchronize on `Class` objects when you can synchronize on `new Object()` or can use `java.util.concurrent`.